# MongoDB - Using Aggregate to get more than one Matching Object in an Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to do exactly what the poster in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026662/mongodb-elemmatch-multiple-elements-in-array) was trying to accomplish. I have documents with the same structure as the poster; in my documents there is an array of objects, each with many keys. I want to bring back all objects (not just the first, as you can with an `$elemMatch`) in that array where a key's value matches my query. I want my query's result to simply be an array of objects, where there is a key in each object that matches my query. For example, in the case of the linked question, I would want to return an array  of objects where `"class":"s2"`. I would want returned:

```
"FilterMetric" : [ 
              {
                "min" : "0.00",
                "max" : "16.83",
                "avg" : "0.00",
                "class" : "s2"
              }, 
              {
                "min" : "0.00",
                "max" : "16.83",
                "avg" : "0.00",
                "class" : "s2"
              } 
                ]
```

I tried all the queries in the answer. The first two queries bring back an empty array in robomongo. In the shell, the command does nothing and return me to the next line. Here's a screenshot of robomongo:

[image]

On the third query in the answer, I get an `unexpected token` for the line where `"input"` is.

I'm using MongoDB version 3.0.2. It appears as if the OP was successful with the answer, so I'm wondering if there is a version issue, or if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the answers in that question seems to be that they're using the wrong casing for `FilterMetric`.  For example, this works:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "FilterMetric.class": "s2" } },
    { "$unwind": "$FilterMetric" },
    { "$match": { "FilterMetric.class": "s2" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "FilterMetric": { "$push": "$FilterMetric" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Hey so that worked, with the addition of: `"$project" : {"_id":0, "array":1}}` at the end in order to remove the objectId. Thanks!