# Retrive nested objects in MongoDB using a combination of AND , OR operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to write a query in mongoDB with an OR operation inside a list of objects and the query should return one field of that document rather than returning the complete document. Let say I have database like this

```
{
"PID : "PID-1",
PriceList : {
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  },
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:3,
    country:X,
  },
  {
    cityId:2,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  }
 }
},
{
"PID : "PID-2",
PriceList : {
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  }
 }
}
```

Now, If I give my input as PID = PID-1, CityId = 1, country = X. Then I should get this o/p

```
{
PriceList : {
{
    cityId:1,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  },
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:3,
    country:X,
  }
 }
}
```

Let's say if I give input as PID = PID-1 and country = X then o/p should be

```
{
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  },
  {
    cityId:1,
    stateId:3,
    country:X,
  },
  {
    cityId:2,
    stateId:2,
    country:X,
  }
}
```

I tried various queries but could not solve it.

Comment: You can test out your queries using https://npm.runkit.com/mingo.

Comment: What you want is the $elemMatch operator

Comment: Hi @kofrasa, I want to use mogoDB with springboot. Not sure about nodejs.

Comment: See answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026662/mongodb-elemmatch-multiple-elements-in-array

Comment: Hi @kofrasa, this helped alot. Can you please help here also ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665046/mapped-result-is-different-from-raw-result-in-mongodb-aggregation