# Mapped result is different from raw result in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

This is how my correct mongo query looks like-

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
{ "$match": { "itemSku": "TOS-16000-00623-00013" } },

{ "$unwind": "$priceInfoList" },

{ "$match": { "priceInfoList.communityId": 3  }},

 { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "priceInfoList": { "$push": "$priceInfoList" }
    }}

])
```

and this is the both actual and the expected output -

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61d815d0538792764c2df576"),
    "priceInfoList" : [ 
        {
            "listPrice" : 0.0,
            "offerPrice" : 0.0,
            "zoneId" : NumberLong(738),
            "communityId" : NumberLong(3),
            "storeType" : "Retailer",
            "principalGroup" : "DRP",
            "isActive" : true
        }, 
        {
            "listPrice" : 0.0,
            "offerPrice" : 0.0,
            "zoneId" : NumberLong(606),
            "communityId" : NumberLong(3),
            "storeType" : "Wholeseller",
            "principalGroup" : "DRP",
            "isActive" : true
        }, 
        {
            "listPrice" : 0.0,
            "offerPrice" : 0.0,
            "zoneId" : NumberLong(606),
            "communityId" : NumberLong(3),
            "storeType" : "Retailer",
            "principalGroup" : "NonDRP",
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the same thing in Spring Boot using Mongo Template but my output from mapped result is different from raw results.
Please check the screenshot.
[image]

You can see that in mapped results I am getting only one priceInfo and that also with null values but my raw results are correct.
I understand that mapped results is giving back PriceInfo rather than List. Here's the code that I have written in spring using mongo template

```
public List<PriceInfo> findByCommunityOrPrincipalGroupOrStoreOrZone(String SKU, Long communityId, String principalGroup, String storeType, Long zoneId) {
    Criteria criteria = generateCriteriaToFilterSegments(communityId,principalGroup,storeType,zoneId);
    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);

    MatchOperation matchOperationSKU = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("itemSku").is(SKU));

    UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("priceInfoList");

    GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group().push("priceInfoList").as("priceInfoList");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperationSKU,unwind,matchOperation,groupOperation);

    AggregationResults<PriceInfo> priceInfosAggregationResults
            = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "product", PriceInfo.class);
    return priceInfosAggregationResults.getMappedResults();
  }

  private Criteria generateCriteriaToFilterSegments(Long communityId, String principalGroup, String storeType, Long zoneId) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    if(communityId != null) {
      criteria.and("priceInfoList.communityId").is(communityId);
    }
    if(principalGroup != null) {
      criteria.and("principalGroup").is(principalGroup);
    }
    if(storeType != null) {
      criteria.and("storeType").is(storeType);
    }
    if(zoneId != null) {
      criteria.and("zoneId").is(zoneId);
    }
    return criteria;
  }
```

How do I correct it ?

EDIT - 1
[image]

Comment: Using `$unwind` and then `{$group: {_id: "$_id"} ...}` is often useless. [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and/or [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) may work better.

Comment: I need multiple values from a list that's why @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Yes, I think `{ $project: { priceInfoList: { $filter: { input: "$priceInfoList", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.communityId", 3] } } } } }` returns the same instead of `$unwind, $match, $group`

Comment: `Aggregation.group()` - the static method is expecting a non-null field. Maybe you should specify the `_id` field.

Comment: @prasad_ I tried to specify the _id field but it still did not work. Can you be more specific on how to define id ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the query gives error. Can you please send the complete one ?

Comment: Something like this: `Aggregation.group("_id")` - this corresponds to the `$group` stage in the native query.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but instead of

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
   { "$match": { "itemSku": "TOS-16000-00623-00013" } },
   { "$unwind": "$priceInfoList" },
   { "$match": { "priceInfoList.communityId": 3 } },
   {
      "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "priceInfoList": { "$push": "$priceInfoList" }
      }
   }
])
```

I would try this:

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
   { $match: { itemSku: "TOS-16000-00623-00013" } },
   {
      $project: {
         priceInfoList: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$priceInfoList",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.communityId", 3] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

The result should be the same and it might be easier to map it to spring. I don't not familiar with spring data.

Comment: Okay. Let me try this. It does give the same results. And what if I need an add condition like communityId = 3 and zoneId = 606 ?

Comment: Then `cond: {$and: [ { $eq: ["$$this.communityId", 3] }, { $eq: ["$$this.zoneId", 606] }]}`

Comment: Now i am getting 3 objects but all of them are null : check edits

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group().push("priceInfoList").as("priceInfoList");
```

to:

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("_id").push("priceInfoList").as("priceInfoList");
```

Your `findByCommunityOrPrincipalGroupOrStoreOrZone` method generated this

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "itemSku" : "TOS-16000-00623-00013"}}, { "$unwind" : "$priceInfoList"}, { "$match" : { "priceInfoList.communityId" : 3}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "priceInfoList" : { "$push" : "$priceInfoList"}}}]}
```

**with `"_id" : null` in `$group`**

---

adding the _id in the group would generate this:

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "itemSku" : "TOS-16000-00623-00013"}}, { "$unwind" : "$priceInfoList"}, { "$match" : { "priceInfoList.communityId" : 3}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "priceInfoList" : { "$push" : "$priceInfoList"}}}]}
```

**with `"_id" : "$_id"` in `$group`**